# Load certificate from ConfigMap in OpenShift to call external service using ApacheHttpClient

Tags: java, spring, https, openshift, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am building an adapter application that should sent the data to an external service using HTTPS. While testing locally (against a mock server), I am saving the certificate in a local truststore and loading it using `loadTrustMaterial(file, password)` method. The difference in productive environment is that the application is running in OpenShift and the certificate is saved in ConfigMap.

**Question:**
How can I retrieve that certificate from ConfigMap in OpenShift (is there any url to the cert?), so my application can call external service?

Here are some code snippets for clarity:

```
private HttpResponse connectToExternalService(String xml) {

        StringEntity stringEntity = null;
        try {

            stringEntity = new StringEntity(xml);
            SSLContext sslContext = this.createSSLContext();
            
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory factory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
            CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(factory).build();

            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            post.setEntity(stringEntity);
            post.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
            return client.execute(post);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            
        }
    }


private SSLContext createSSLContext() {
        File file = new File("path to the truststore");
        try {
            char[] password = "password".toCharArray();
            return SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(file, password).build();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException | KeyStoreException e) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As config map being used to hold the certificate, the same can be mounted as file inside the container.  Please refer k8s [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#populate-a-volume-with-data-stored-in-a-configmap) to load as file.  Post that add it trust store during container start.

Comment: Yes, mount it as a volume.